# Converting Marshal.Copy Bitmap to Silverlight Equivalent

Tags: silverlight, writeablebitmap

I am having a problem converting the following code snippet for an existing component into Silverlight.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

data is `byte[]` and `width` and `height` are the required image width and height.

Can anyone share some ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
{
    BitmapImage im = new BitmapImage();
    im.SetSource(ms);
    this.imageControl.Source = im;
}
```